# How can I find the perplexity of a text by the perplexity of its sentences?

Tags: natural-language-processing

For a bigram language model, I can calculate the perplexity of sentences of a test document. However, I'm not sure what would be the perplexity of the whole document. Should I get the average of the perplexities of sentences?

Comment: It’s up to you. *You* get to define the perplexity of a document as you please.